# How to click on a button that does not have an id?

Tags: testing, android-espresso, barista

I want to click on a button that does not have id. This button has a class name - ImageButton. 
Also, the button is located on the tollbar
I can not do this because I do not have id

```
onView(...).perform(click());
```

Trying to use Baristo, but this does not work:

```
click(withClassName(ImageButton.class));
```

Comment: Why not just include an id?

Comment: I have no right to do this